# control cursor in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, text-cursor

I wrote the following script to check my servers:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /tmp/res-ok.txt     1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/res-failed.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null

echo "***********************************************"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+      PINGING SERVERS: Is UP OR DOWN       +*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "***********************************************"

echo " ================                 ============ "
echo "|   IP ADDRESS   |               |   STATUS   |"
echo " ================                 ============ "

while read ip; do
    ping $ip -s 1 -c 1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "  $ip                      UP"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-ok.txt
    elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "  $ip                      DOWN"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-failed.txt
    fi
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

done <<____HERE

____HERE

ok=`wc -l /tmp/res-ok.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
failed=`wc -l /tmp/res-failed.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

echo You have $ok servers UP
echo You have $failed servers DOWN
```

how can I tell my script that show `STATUS column`[the second column] in the specific place?[exactly]
I think I should control cursor..how?
any idea?
thank you

Comment: I know:Position the Cursor:
          \033[<L>;<C>H
             Or
          \033[<L>;<C>f
          puts the cursor at line L and column C. /// how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your Problem correctly, your Layout is broken, because you have IP-adresses of different lengths. Depending on how much different they are, you could get a better fitting layout by using tabulators instead of just blanks:

```
echo -e "  $ip\t\t\t\tDOWN"
```

... or by piping your output through **column**:

```
output="$output `echo -e "\n$ip UP"`"
...
## Outputting your output:
echo -e "$output" | column -t
```

Result:

```
172.16.2.4        UP
172.16.2.5        UP
192.168.178.200   UP
192.168.178.254   UP
```

For the latter to look perfect, you might have to adjust the width of your welcome-header to the resulting width of your output.

You could also add more blank columns in between your fields by adding a seperator:

```
output="$output `echo -e "\n$ip  - UP"`"
```

Result:

```
172.16.2.4       -   UP
172.16.2.5       -   UP
192.168.178.200  -   UP
192.168.178.254  -   UP
192.168.178.254  -   UP
```

So after those changes your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /tmp/res-ok.txt     1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/res-failed.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null

echo "***********************************************"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+      PINGING SERVERS: Is UP OR DOWN       +*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "***********************************************"

echo " =============          ============ "
echo "| IP ADDRESS  |        |   STATUS   |"
echo " =============          ============ "

output=""    ## Unset the variable, in case it still contains anything.

while read ip; do
    ping $ip -s 1 -c 1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        output="$output `echo "\n$ip - UP"`"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-ok.txt
    elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        output="$output `echo "\n$ip - DOWN"`"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-failed.txt
    fi
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

done <<____HERE

____HERE

echo -e "$output" | column -t

ok=`wc -l /tmp/res-ok.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
failed=`wc -l /tmp/res-failed.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

echo You have $ok servers UP
echo You have $failed servers DOWN
```

Comment: can you edit my script? I didn't get it..thank you..I tried but no result

Comment: For that I'd have to propose another answer - the whole thing does not fit into a comment. Basically what I meant was, that you build a variable (called it "output") in your while-loop, that contains all the lines you output via echo in the current version. After the loop is finished you echo your output-variable and format it with the help of column.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about simply editing my answer - just did. The edited version of your script is now in there. Can't test it due to the lack of fitting input-files, but I think it should work :-).

Comment: Your code has a very small problem I corrected it.but the edited one is not here :( :D

Comment: If you tell me where in the code the error is I gladly correct my answer.

Comment: see the answer part :) and thank you for your help..I learnt sth new

Comment: there was no error actually...echo "-------" was not in a correct place

Comment: can you tell me what the role of output="" and "culumn -t" is? :)

Comment: For the first part of your question, you'll probably find the answer in the comment regarding that in the same line.
Column is a command to format output in nicely ordered columns - see "man column" for more information.

Comment: ohh..I didn't know about column command... :D thank you dear friend

Answer (score 0):

The final answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: ./server-status.sh <ip-list>"
    exit 1
fi

rm -f /tmp/whole.txt      1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/res-ok.txt     1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/res-failed.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null

echo "***********************************************"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+      PINGING SERVERS: Is UP OR DOWN       +*"
echo "*+                                           +*"
echo "*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*"
echo "***********************************************"

echo " ================                 ============ "
echo "|   IP ADDRESS   |               |   STATUS   |"
echo " ================                 ============ "

output=""
while read ip; do
    ping $ip -s 1 -c 1 -W 1 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    output="$output `echo "\n$ip -------------------- UP"`"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-ok.txt
    elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    output="$output `echo "\n$ip -------------------- DOWN"`"
        echo $ip >> /tmp/res-failed.txt
    fi
done < $1

echo -e "$output" | column -t

cat /tmp/res-ok.txt >> /tmp/whole.txt
cat /tmp/res-failed.txt >> /tmp/whole.txt

total=`wc -l /tmp/whole.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
ok=`wc -l /tmp/res-ok.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`
failed=`wc -l /tmp/res-failed.txt | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

echo "UP:    $ok"
echo "DOWN:  $failed"
echo "TOTAL: $total"
```